# Measurable functions and Borel sets

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

Show that function $f$ from $E$ to $R^*$ defined on a measurable set $E$ is measurable if and only if:

1. The sets $f^{-1}(\infty)$ and $f^{-1}(-\infty)$ are measurable and
2. For each Borel set $B$, $f^{-1}(B)$ is measurable.

Comment: This is the usual definition of measurability for extended real valued functions. What is your definition?

Comment: An extended real valued function f is defined on a measurable set E is said to be Lebesgue Measurable if the set E(f>a) is measurable for all real numbers a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: One way is very easy. The two conditions imply measurability.

Suppose $f$ is measurable. Then $f^{-1} (\infty)=\cap_n [E \cap (f>n)]$ and $f^{-1} (-\infty)=\cap_n [E \cap (f>-n)^{c}]$.

Comment: Thanks I got this , the problem I am facing is the with condition in part b and other side of the theorem